# Is there any good idiom that means you've been outplayed?

Tags: idiom-request

Is there any good idiom that means you've been outplayed? Can you think of an idiom like that? I am looking for an idiom I can use to describe that someone got outplayed in a board game like chess. Is there any good idiom for that?

Comment: Beaten? Thrashed? It depends on what context it's in.

Comment: You could say [*pwned*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pwn) depending on the audience (making sure they understand internet/video game slang).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Checkmate* works in most contexts, but is not a good choice when you're actually writing about chess...

> 2. To defeat completely.

(source: [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/checkmate))

---

Another option is *whitewash*:

> (verb) 3: to hold (an opponent) scoreless in a game or contest
>   (noun) 3: a defeat in a contest in which the loser fails to score

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whitewash))

Comment: Yes, but it does not work for board games in general.